# How to remove white background on a simple bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to remove the white background on a simple bar chart.

I've tried

- backgroundColor: null
- backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'

None seem to set the background color.  Any ideas?
jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xv26bet4/)

```
     $('#container').highcharts({
    credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  backgroundColor: null,
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use settings for the `chart` object at the root object level.

Move them into `chart`, and you're all set:

```
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0],
  backgroundColor: null
}
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xv26bet4/1/